# Writing GUI frontend for commandline application in Mac OS X

Tags: user-interface, macos, command-line

I am wondering if there is a source of information on how to develop a GUI frontend application for a commandline one in Mac OS X in, but not necessarily, Xcode?

Specifically, I would love a GUI frontend that lets me specify arguments to pass to the commandline program.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would use Python + Tkinter or other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several options. One of the most commonly used programs to create GUI "front ends" to a script is [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus). However, this does not allow the user to pass arguments like you want. The other option is creating a Cocoa application and using the [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html) class to run your script with arguments that the user specifies in an [NSTextField](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/index.html). In your case, I think creating a full Cocoa application written in Objective-C is overkill.

The most simple way to get what you want and still have it easy is to create a script written in AppleScript. This is a bare bones script that would do the trick:

```
display dialog "Enter arguments:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Run"} default button 2
set scriptArguments to text returned of result
do shell script "/path/to/script " & scriptArguments
```

Comment: You can use CocoaDialog[1] with Platypus to accept user input.

Also, Pashua[2] lets you create more complex UIs.

[1] http://cocoadialog.sourceforge.net/

[2] http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/

Answer (score 5):

Check out:

- [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)
- [iHook](http://ihook.org/)