# Mac C run in window

Tags: c, macos

Is it possible to run compiled C and C++ Files on a mac without opening and running it in terminal?
E.G is there a separate GUI i can use for executing compiled c programs?

Comment: [Writing GUI frontend for commandline application in Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346171/writing-gui-frontend-for-commandline-application-in-mac-os-x) might contain a good answer for you.

Comment: Couldn't you double click the applications in finder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal IS a GUI; it provides you with access to the shell while you're still in the window system.  I don't know what you'd want this other GUI to do that Terminal isn't doing for you.  You would still need to provide the file path to this other program, which it would then load for execution, and it would still need to open standard input / standard output, etc.

If you have the source code, however, you can use an IDE.  [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) works well for that, but there are plenty of others.

Comment: The program executed currently using terminal, but i would like a interface that users see more inviting, other than the terminal, however the user still needs to provide user input

Comment: @Daniel: So you want to create a gui for your program?

Comment: @Lucas It's a terminal application, but i just need a GUI for the user input and status actions

Comment: Eclipse is not good for C development.  On a Mac XCode works well.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Pashua](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/).

Comment: Pashua does not support C/c++ programs

Comment: Pashua can read interface definitions from a file or stdin, so any language can be used to drive Pashua.

Answer (score 0):

You can run/develop C/C++ programs in XCode on Mac OS X.   From within XCode its cmd-B to build, cmd-enter to run.  XCode is the Mac IDE which you can download or its comes as an optional install or your Mac OS install disks.

XCode also supports code completion  -  hit ESC.

Also see:  [Working comfortably in C using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971083/working-comfortably-in-c-using-eclipse/)